# Middleware class not called on api requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I've created a basic webAPI project (blank web project with webAPI checked) and added the owin nuget packages to the project.

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Owin

I've then created a Logging class, and hooked it up via startup

```
using AppFunc = System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Startup Called");
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

        appBuilder.Use(typeof(LoggingMiddleware));
    }
}

public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private AppFunc Next { get; set; }

    public LoggingMiddleware(AppFunc next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Begin Request");

        await Next.Invoke(environment);

        Debug.WriteLine("End Request");
    }
}
```

When I run the project, and the default page opens, I see the Begin/End requests called (twice, as it happens, not sure why that is).

However, if I try to call an `/api` route (such as `/api/ping/'), the request completes successfully, but I do not see the Begin/End request states in the log.

What am I missing with this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Owin executes the middleware items in the order that they are registered, ending at the call to the controller (`appBuilder.UseWebApi(config)`) which does not appear to call `next.Invoke()`. Given that the code in the question has the Logging Middleware class registered *after* the `UseWebApi` call, this causes it to never be called for API requests.

Changing the code to:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        //.....

        //This must be registered first
        appBuilder.Use(typeof(LoggingMiddleware));

        //Register this last
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

resolves the issue.

Comment: Saved the day!! :D

Comment: > *which does not appear to call next.Invoke()* Uhhhh why not?? C'mon microsoft...